# Are wizards immune to Keldon warlords’ calls?

Tags: books, wizards, magic-the-gathering

In Magic the Gathering: Final Sacrifice, Towser summons a Keldon warlord. We see the warlord can simply shout “Attend me” and “Fight” to the natives on the island, and they all start fighting each other in a massive bloodbath. I’m wondering why the onlooking wizards don’t also start fighting? I’m also wondering why the wizards are gathering an army to fight Gull and Greensleeves if the warlord could just tell them to fight each other.

Do the commands of Keldon warlords only work on commoners and the simple minded?